# Nested query not grabbing values in oracle from main query in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I get an error on the nested query. I've tried to select the id from the parent query by giving it a alias and calling it in the subquery. How can I grab id from mytable outside query?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable t
WHERE (
SELECT count(*) number_of_weekdays FROM
        (
            SELECT start_date, to_char(start_date+(level-1), 'fmday') d_day
            FROM (  select strt_dt as start_date , trunc(sysdate) as end_date from mytable where id = t.id   )
            connect by level <= end_date - start_date + 2 
        )
        WHERE d_day IN (
            select rtrim(ltrim(regexp_substr(intv,'[^,]+', 1, level))) from ( select intv from mytable where id = t.id )
            connect by regexp_substr(intv, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
        )

) <= col1
```

***column I mostly focus on:***

```
INTV                                  | STRT_DT
--------------------------------------------------
3, monday, tuesday, thursday, sunday  | 07-MAY-18
```

ERROR:

```
ORA-00904: "T"."ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

Comment: What's the `CREATE TABLE` statement of `mytable`?

Comment: CREATE TABLE mytable
(
ID            NUMBER        NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
CRTD_AT       TIMESTAMP(6)  NOT NULL ,
UPDT_AT       TIMESTAMP(6)  NOT NULL ,
STRT_DT       DATE          NOT NULL ,
END_DT        DATE                   ,
INTV          VARCHAR2(150)          ,
COL1       NUMBER(20)             ,
RRNC_PATT     VARCHAR2(20)           
);

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated with example data

Comment: Correlation to a subquery more than one level below the "outer" query should be supported according to the SQL Standard. However, Oracle did not support it historically, and the documentation for 12.1 and 12.2 still says it is prohibited. However, it did work in 10.1 and 11.1, but that was "fixed" (meaning, it would throw an error) in 10.2 and 11.2. Even though the documentation still says it is not supported, it DOES work in 12.1 and 12.2. So, **it depends** on your version of Oracle!

Comment: What this query is supposed to do ? It looks at first glance that this query will be very slow, say the table has 100.000 records with start-date 2018-01-01, then the first subquery generates about 180 rows for each record, 180 miltiplied by 10000 gives 18.000.000 records to be processed by the query.

Comment: The query is supposed to count the weekdays based on the selected days in a column from the starting date to today. For example if Monday and Thursday are in the a particular row then I count how many Mondays and Tuesdays are from a beginning date until now. In the case of my example and today 2 of June this query should return 15. I am open to suggestions if you think it can be improved.

Comment: I meant to say Thursday and not Tuesday by the way.

Comment: Works for me in 12.2. I don't have 12.1 to test with and I can't find the limit in the documentation, but some limitations are removed in 12c.

Comment: I have Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0):

From a subquery, you can only refer to data of the directly outer query. You cannot access the data across several levels of queries and subqueries.

In your case, you have three levels of subqueries, i.e. four levels overall and you try to access data of the outermost query from the innermost one.

Comment: Replace alias `a` with `b` in order to remove the ambiguity between table name and alias. If you do, it doesn't work anymore. Without the replacement `a.a` refers to table `a` as specified in the innermost subquery, not to the alias `a` from the outermost query as you probably intended.

Comment: @Codo_ Ah, my mistake. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: No wait, I forgot to change one spot, which caused the problem. I Changed all the `a`s in the aliases to `b` now and it's still working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/710f7/5

Comment: While the documentation has always said that correlation more than one level deep is not supported, in reality it **is** supported in versions 10.1, 11.1, 12.1 and 12.2 but not in versions up to 9.x, and also not supported in 10.2 and 11.2.

Comment: This will depend on the Oracle version. The OP uses 11g, but some limitations were removed in 12c.